# Writing to Application Log on a remote Windows 7 machine

Tags: event-log

I need to write to an application log on a remote Window 7 computer. When my PC was running Windows 7, I could do so using a Write-Entry cmdlet, eventcreate, WriteEvent API, or LogEvent in VBS. Since upgrading my PC to Windows 10 (v1511), this no longer works failing with an error "The procedure number is out of range".  I can write to an application log on a remote Window 10 machine, but the problem is with the remote (not firewalled) Window 7 PC. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?